# How to create a constructed generic type without specifying any type parameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

When we have something like this:

```
interface ISomething<U,V> { ... }
class Something<U,V> : ISomething<U,V> { ... }
```

`typeof(ISomething<,>)` and `typeof(Something<,>)` will result in a "Generic type definition". But if we get to the interface type as the interface implemented by the class, it will be a constructed type, that none of its type parameters are actually bound:

```
typeof(Something<,>).GetInterfaces().SingleOrDefault()
```

MSDN specifically mentions this. What I want, is to construct the same type (constructed type) of `ISomething<,>` directly (without sub-classing and them looking for the base type), and I could not find any way to do so.

Additional info:

I even tried this:

```
Type t1 = typeof(ISomething<,>);
Type t2 = t1.MakeGenericType(t1.GetGenericArguments()) // Yields a generic type definition

Type t3 = typeof(Something<,>).GetInterfaces().SingleOrDefault();
```

In the above code:

`t1.Equals(t2)` is true, but `t1.Equals(t3)` is false, obviously because `t3` is constructed.

Surprisingly, `t1.GetGenericArguments()[0].Equals(t3.GetGenericArguments()[0])` is false, although both are open (IsGenericParameter = true), and I couldn't find any difference in their properties.

And here's why I need to do this: I need a canonical form of storing Type objects in a list. The objects sometimes come from base classes / interfaces (such as t3 above) and sometimes directly (such as t1). I will need to be able to compare these to each other. I can't store the generic type definition (using `.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`) because sometimes I will have a partially open constructed generic type (like ISomething), and GetGenericTypeDefinition will give me a type without any type arguments specified.

The only way for making the types canonical that I've thought might work, is to check if all of the type arguments are unbound, and do a GetGenericTypeDefinition. Otherwise keep the constructed type.

Comment: I don't think this works: "check if all of the type arguments are unbound, and do a GetGenericTypeDefinition. Otherwise keep the constructed type."  Suppose the type you have is `I<U, U>`.  All the type arguments are unbound type parameters, but that is a different type than `I<U, V>`.

Comment: Re: "Surprisingly..." -- this is not surprising at all. I suspect that part of the confusion of all of this is that you have two completely different types called "U" and two completely different types called "V".  Of course `I<,>` is different from the `I<U, V>` in the implemented interface list; the former is parameterized with the `<U, V>` declared by `I`, and the other is parameterized with the `<U, V>` declared by `Something`. Just because the type parameters have the same names does not make them the same type.

Comment: If I have a constructed `I<U,U>`, and call GetGenericTypeDefinition() on it, will it give me `typeof(I<U,V>)`?

Comment: That's right, I was confusing the two. Actually, I just got why the base types are constructed! I need to think about my original problem more,... but I think I still need some way to compare (or look up the types in a list)

Comment: "If I have a constructed `I<U,U>`, and call `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` on it, will it give me `typeof(I<U,V>)`? "  -- that depends on which `U` and `V` are in scope where you call `typeof`!.  It will give you `typeof(I<,>)` which is identical to `typeof(I<U,V>)` where the `U` and `V` in scope are the `U` and `V` declared by `interface I<U, V>`. You see how confusing it is to have two things with the same name?

Comment: Some jargon might help.  A generic type constructed with its own generic type parameters in the right order is called the "instance type". So if you have `interface I<S, T>{ I<S, T> M(); }` then `typeof(I<,>)` and `typeof(I<,>).GetMethod("M").ReturnType` are the same type; they are both the *instance type*. That is, they are the type object for `I<,>` constructed with its own declared type parameters `S` and `T`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting yourself all messed up here. Examine the output of this program and make sure that you understand it. Here I've alpha-renamed the type parameters so that there is no unclarity due to two things both named U:

```
interface I<S, T>
{
    I<S, T> M();
}

class C<U, V> : I<U, V>
{
    public I<U, V> M() {return null;}
    public C<U, V> N() {return null;}
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var i1 = typeof(I<,>);
        var i2 = typeof(I<int, int>);
        var i3 = i2.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        var i4 = i1.GetMethod("M").ReturnType;

        var c1 = typeof(C<,>);
        var c2 = typeof(C<int, int>);
        var c3 = c2.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        var c4 = c1.GetMethod("N").ReturnType;

        var i5 = c1.GetMethod("M").ReturnType;
        var i6 = c1.GetInterfaces()[0];

        System.Console.WriteLine(i1 == i2); // false -- I<,> is not I<int, int>
        System.Console.WriteLine(i1 == i3); // true  -- I<int,int>'s decl is I<,>
        System.Console.WriteLine(i1 == i4); // true  -- I<,> is I<S, T>
        System.Console.WriteLine(i1 == i5); // false -- I<S, T> is not I<U, V>
        System.Console.WriteLine(i1 == i6); // false -- I<S, T> is not I<U, V>

        System.Console.WriteLine(c1 == c2); // false -- C<,> is not C<int, int>
        System.Console.WriteLine(c1 == c3); // true  -- C<int,int>'s decl is C<,>
        System.Console.WriteLine(c1 == c4); // true  -- C<,> is C<U,V>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, you're awesome. I realized my mistake, but your sample code is great. I guess I can make the type I want by passing generic args of the class for making GenericType out of the interface - i.e. `t1.MakeGenericType(typeof(Something<,>).GetGenericArguments())`. Am I right? - Although, I know that this won't help me in my original problem.

Comment: @You're welcome. You wouldn't believe the sorts of problems like this we have to solve in the compiler. It can get very confusing!

Comment: Can I ask one question? So far I havent done much around Genrics, so I would like to know what they are good for? Whats the point in them (creating, using...)? thx for the answer

Comment: @Mitja: Of course you can ask a question. **Do so by posting a question**. That's what this whole site is for!

Comment: Try googling your question, there's a lot of material for you out there. The answer would be longer than what SO allows for comments :)

Comment: @Mitja Bonca: What about the Generic collection classes? Being able to have a collection of a specific object provides you more efficiency and the protection of the type system.  Using a collection of objects and casting them whenever you retrieve them leaves room for cast exceptions and makes code a little bit harder to maintain.